# Is the AIA from "The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo" real?

Tags: historical-context, scandinavian-languages, stieg-larsson, the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo

In *The Girl With the Dragon Tattoo*, Blomkvist's friend Robban mentions a government agency called the AIA (Agency for Industrial Assistance), which was supposed to "help industry in the former Eastern Bloc get back on its feet." Searching on the internet, I can't find anything about the AIA. Does anyone know if it was real, or modeled on something that was real?

Answer (score 1):

Google Search for:

> "Agency for Industrial Assistance" wiki

Gets me a link for [this pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/299373492.pdf) that says, in reference to the translator:

> Keeland was more inclined to domesticate such names; for example he translates a government agency named *SIB* as A.I.A.

Not sure what SIB is. Here's [Wikipedia: Government agencies in Sweden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_agencies_in_Sweden).

But the PDF's Swedish section of book quotes says:

> SIB stod för Styrelsen för Industriellt Bistånd

So, yeah, the SIB is whatever that is, which is not the [Swedish International Development Cooperation Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_International_Development_Cooperation_Agency), as this other quote says:

> En av deras tomtar hade förväxlat SIB med SIDA

> One of their henchmen had confused A.I.A. with the Swedish International Development Authority

---

A search for "Styrelsen för Industriellt Bistånd" gives no results that aren't based on the book, so I assume it's a fictional agency.